# ActionListener works perfectly after second time it's pressed

Tags: actionlistener

entercommand.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String userinput = enterword.getText();
            String userinput2 = entersecondword.getText();
            if (" ".equals(userinput) || " ".equalsIgnoreCase(userinput2)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The space is empty please try again");

            } else {
                enterword.setText(" ");
                entersecondword.setText(" ");
                System.out.println("test");
                JapanesestudiesExcel JE = new JapanesestudiesExcel();
                JE.JapanesestudiesExcel(userinput, userinput2);

            }
            ;
        }
    });
```

It checks input in the fieldbox the second time the Listener is fired, but the first time it does not work. TO better explain this, when a user enters nothing it doesn't check for an empty string it writes the empty box into excel. The second time the ActionListener is fired it checks perfectly and reports the message back to the user. Why does this occur?

Answer (score 0):

you're testing this for a space, not the empty string:

```
(" ".equals(userinput) || " ".equalsIgnoreCase(userinput2))
```

remove the space:

```
("".equals(userinput) || "".equalsIgnoreCase(userinput2))
```

Also, this is why it works the second time you click it:

```
enterword.setText(" ");
entersecondword.setText(" ");
```

You're setting the field to a space, so it will be true the next time around.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem. I am unable to give you reputation, but I do appreciate this.